# Ajax refresh page content instead of div content

Tags: ajax

Is there a way to refresh the entire page content instead of just a div?

Comment: @OP, it's not really ajax if you do that, is it?

Answer (score 2):

what exactly do you want here? you can write 1 javascript line to refresh entire page

```
 window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* replace the content of the `body` tag. It's just like replacing the content of an ordinary `div`. To access the body tag use `document.body` or `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`.

If you do a normal page reload with `window.location` you will have the CSS and JavaScript in the head reloaded, so that will take more resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to send the browser to a new URL:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

But, at that point, you're kind of defeating the point of AJAX.  Most of the time, you'd want to download only the data you need from the server, and rewrite the contents of only those parts of the page that change.  It's generally a better experience for the user, that way.